# what does it mean when a smart pointer is showing negative usecount

Tags: c++

I am getting a segfault error when calling p_o->p_order_->somefunc(). I looked in the debugger and saw that the counters of the shared pointer seem strange. It shows a neg count for shared ptr and a large coutn for weak ptr (which I never used)

```
p_o             @0x60c3331          Online::sptrOrder
    data        @0x60c3331          Online::OrderMgr
    p_order_    0x20000000009b6b7   Online::Order *
    id_         40                  long
    usecount    -1602224128         int
    weakcount   636599              int
    px          1.99                double
    is_fruit_   false               bool
    size        10                  long
```

Do I misunderstand the information presented here or is there something odd going on?
Also, I am not really familiar with the debugger, yet.. Does the lack of an @address of the line

```
p_order_    0x20000000009b6b7   Online::Order
```

imply the pointer p_order_ (which is a raw pointer) is not valid/null,..? Or is that 0x20000000009b6b7 some sort of address?

Comment: It means that your code has a bug somewhere, that resulted in a corrupted heap.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] if you want more of an answer than "sothing somewhere has trashed the heap", which is about all we can say with this information.

Answer (score -1):

The segfault and the apparently garbage usecount value indicates your smart pointer object isn't a valid object. Do you have a reference to a smart pointer object that was declared on the stack and doesn't actually exist any more?